# Google sheets, if statement multiple conditions

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, worksheet-function

Trying to make an if statement that will return 4 outcomes based on the contents of the cell

If the cell is "Yes", "No", "NA", "Unknown", to return 0, 1, 2, 3 respectively.

I can use  `If(A1="Yes", 0,1)`  but not sure how to handle the other conditions

Answer (score 6):

`SWITCH` would be a better call:

```
=SWITCH(A1,"Yes",0,"No",1,"N/A",2,"Unknown",3,"I'-'I")
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try:

```
=IF(A1="Yes",0,IF(A1="No",1,IF(A1="Unknown",3,2)))
```

Anything other than the given selection in A1 (and not an error) and the formula would return `2`.

Answer (score 1):

The concept you are asking for in the Google Docs Editors help center is called "nested function". This concept refers to using a function as a parameter of another function.

The syntax for IF is

```
IF(logical_expression, value_if_true, value_if_false)
```

You could replace logical_expression, value_if_true and/or value_if_false with another IF. For this specific case, try

```
=IF(A1="Yes",0,IF(A1="No",1,IF(A1="NA",2,IF(A1="Unknown",3,NA())))
```

`#N/A` will be returned if A1 contains an unexpected value.

Reference

- [Add formulas and functions to a spreadsheet](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/46977?hl=en)